# related items in loop creates many duplicate queries

Tags: django, django-models

Rendering a page gets really slow when related objects are requested in a template.

```
class Item(models.Model):
   name =  models.CharField(max_length=160)
   ...

class Box(models.Model):
   ...
   items = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) 

#template  
{% for item in items %}  
   {{ item.box_set.first }}  
   {{ item.box_set.latest }}  
{% endfor %}
```

Debug toolbar shows there many duplicate queries.
Why is this happening? Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

The Django ORM has to make a request to the database when accessing a related field unless it's already cached. The main ways of caching the related objects are via `select_related` and `prefetch_related`.

What you're trying to do is a bit more difficult; you're trying to get two specific items from a collection. You can use `.annotate()` and `Subquery` to pull singular fields from a related model. This would be useful if you just wanted to display single field from box, but if you need the whole box instance this won't work.